# How do I type the return of an useAsyncData call in Nuxt 3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, pinia

How can I type the returned 'data' from a useAsyncData call that fetches some data from a pinia store?

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useSale } from "~/stores/sale";

const saleStore = useSale();

const { data: vehicle, pending } = useAsyncData<{ data: IVehicle }>(
  "vehicle",
  () => saleStore.getVehicle
);
</script>
```

Currently my vscode gives me the following error

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(handler: (ctx?: NuxtApp) => Promise<{ data: IVehicle; }>, options?: AsyncDataOptions<{ data: IVehicle; }, { data: IVehicle; }, KeysOf<{ data: IVehicle; }>>): AsyncData<...>', gave the following error.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(key: string, handler: (ctx?: NuxtApp) => Promise<{ data: IVehicle; }>, options?: AsyncDataOptions<{ data: IVehicle; }, { data: IVehicle; }, KeysOf<{ data: IVehicle; }>>): AsyncData<...>', gave the following error.ts(2769)
asyncData.d.ts(35, 143): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.
```

**Update**

I tried to type it like mentioned in the comments:

```
const { data: vehicle, pending } = await useAsyncData<IVehicle>(
  "vehicle",
  () => saleStore.vehicle
);
```

But still error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(handler: (ctx?: NuxtApp) => Promise<IVehicle>, options?: AsyncDataOptions<IVehicle, IVehicle, KeysOf<IVehicle>>): AsyncData<...>', gave the following error.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(key: string, handler: (ctx?: NuxtApp) => Promise<IVehicle>, options?: AsyncDataOptions<IVehicle, IVehicle, KeysOf<IVehicle>>): AsyncData<...>', gave the following error.ts(2769)
asyncData.d.ts(35, 143): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.
```

Answer (score 2):

asyncData type defined here https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-async-data#type

You can define return data type as bellow (`useAsyncData<IVehicle>` not `useAsyncData<{ data: IVehicle }>`)

```
const { data: vehicle, pending } = useAsyncData<IVehicle>(
  "vehicle",
  () => saleStore.getVehicle
);
```

Comment: Thanks for te response! I tried it like that but still got same error. I updated my question with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue in a very similar use case with `useAsyncData()`. However in my instance I'm using async with a (Nuxt3) Composable that returns an async Promise.

I pieced my solution together from reading this article:
https://blog.logrocket.com/async-await-in-typescript/

It seems that the approach is to forget Typing `useAsyncData()` and instead Type what is returned by your call within `useAsyncData()`. This might look something like the below.

**YourComponent.vue**

```
// Revert this line back to default syntax
const { data: vehicle, pending } = useAsyncData(
  "vehicle",
  () => saleStore.getVehicle
);
```

**Sale.js**

```
const useSale = async (): Promise<IVehicle> => {

  // Logic here

}
```

This approach has worked for me, but I'm not certain you can integrate this exact syntax with your store. You might need to experiment to find the right place within getVehicle. If you can't get it to work try pasting in some of the code from your store and I will try to help further.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue and adding types to the handler() worked for me.

```
const { data: vehicle, pending } = await useAsyncData(
  "vehicle",
  (): Promise<IVehicle> => saleStore.vehicle
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).